# Deleteing data from database based on a jcomboBox throws an error

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, sql-delete

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)     
{                                         

    Connection conn=DbCon.conDB();
    //String Mname =jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String sql="delete Name from nowshowingmovie where Name = '"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString()+"'";
    try{

        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
     //   pst.executeQuery();
        pst.executeUpdate(sql);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Movie Deleted Sucessfully");
    }

   catch(SQLException e)
   {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
   }

}
```

Comment: You are not supposed to `delete Name from ...`. Just change this into `delete from ...` (deleting has nothing to do with columns).

Comment: OMG tnx alot !! it works !!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 issues:

1. In general the syntax for DELETE is

   `String sql = "delete from nowshowingmovie where Name = '"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString()+"'";`
2. `PreparedStatement` doesn't use the SQL String, i.e. just use `pst.executeUpdate()`

Side note: Since you're already using a `PreparedStatement` you can use a placeholder to avoid [`SQL injection`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks rather than using `String` concatenation.

```
String sql = "delete from nowshowingmovie where Name = ?";
pst.setString(1, jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString());
pst.executeUpdate();
```